# JavaFx TextArea freezes when calling appendText() inside a loop

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, javafx-2

So i'm trying to update a TextArea very frequently from a loop

```
// This code makes the UI freez and the textArea don't get updated
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    staticTextArea.appendText("dada \n");
}
```

I also tried to implement a BlockingQueue to create tasks that updates the TextArea, this solved the freezing issue of the UI but the TextArea stops getting updated after some hundred loops, but in the same time System.out.print("dada \n"); works as it should.

```
    private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
    private static Thread mainWorker;

    private static void updateTextArea() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++) {
            addJob(() -> {
                staticTextArea.appendText("dada \n");
                System.out.print("dada \n");
            });
        }


    }

    private static void addJob(Runnable t) {
        if (mainWorker == null) {
            mainWorker = new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        queue.take().run();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            mainWorker.start();
        }
        queue.add(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you're blocking the UI thread.

JavaFX offers the `Platform` class, which exposes the `runLater` method. 
That method can be used to run long-running tasks on the JavaFX application thread (that is different from the UI thread).

```
final Runnable appendTextRunnable = 
      () -> {
         for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            staticTextArea.appendText("dada \n");
         }
      };

Platform.runLater(appendTextRunnable);
```